# Is there a difference between initializing List and ArrayList?

Tags: java, initialization

I have the code:

```
List<Integer> grades = new ArrayList<Integer>();
ArrayList<Integer> grades1 = new ArrayList<>();
```

what is the difference between the first way of initializing an ArrayList and the second way?

Comment: Did you search on this at all? I've seen the same question answered here a couple times this past week.

Comment: Generally you want to use ``List<Integer> grades = new ArrayList<Integer>();`` because this may allow you to change the type of grades to a different sort of List.

Answer (score -1):

Essentially, ArrayList is a kind of List, which means, as NomadMaker pointed out, ArrayLists can be initialized into Lists.

```
List<Integer> grades = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

If you plan on changing `grades` to a different kind of list, you will want to use `List<>`, otherwise there's no difference.

Comment: Yes there is a difference.  Sometimes the implementation has additional methods that the interface doesn't specify.  In order to take advantage of those you will want to assign to the implementation type (class name) and not the interface.